# How to obtain an affordable electronic paper programmable kit or similar?

Tags: embedded-systems

I'm really interested in playing around with the electronic paper technology, but I don't really want to program any commercial device (kindle or whatever).

I have some ideas and I want to start. How do I get a screen of electronic paper, a chip and how to start programming for it (language, interface)

Comment: This question is more about hardware than programming and should be migrated to [Electronics](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: We don't do a lot of migrations to [Electronics.SE], so I'm checking with their moderators to make sure this question is on-topic there.

Comment: This question is a bit too broad to be a good fit for electronics, but you already have answers on where to get started, feel free to come ask as you get into the nitty gritty of it.

Answer (score 5):

You can buy a [small E-paper display](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10150) and [breakout board](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10304) from Sparkfun for about $25 and $15 respectively. Hook them up to an [Arduino](http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9950) or other microcontroller board and you're ready to start writing code. The language and tools you'll use will obviously depend on what controller you choose; for Arduino, you can find a lot of information at [http://arduino.cc](http://arduino.cc/en/Guide/HomePage).

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking about arduino, but I needed a display, very interesting.

Comment: from the [small E-paper display link](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/retired/10150): "This product has been retired from our catalog and is no longer for sale."

Answer (score 1):

The older versions of the nook can be fairly easily rooted allowing you basically full access for less than $100. They don't have much in the way of horsepower they run android as a base operating system and I've heard they can run other flavors of Linux once rooted via micro SD card. You could easily take the device apart and mount it however you like, it's not difficult.

E-Ink does sell [developer kits](http://www.nexternal.com/eink/storefront.aspx) to make your own but they drift into the $1500 range.